# PHP: process CSV acquired from imap attachment

Tags: php, imap, email-attachments

I know, that there is `fgetcsv` function which process each row of csv file. but what if I don't have file, but attachment (string?) acquired from email by imap php functions (like `imap_fetchstructure`, `imap_fetchbody`, `imap_base64`...).

is there any simple possibility, or must I process it manually?

Comment: Well you could create a temporary file, obviously.

Comment: If you have PHP >= 5.3.0, you could use http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.str-getcsv.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also the [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) function (from PHP >= 5.3)

Comment: what about multiline csv? I tried `str_getcsv($attach, ",", "\r\n")`. this don't get `"\r\n"` I think. next tried `array_chunk(str_getcsv($attach, ","), 9);` but this get last entry from first line and first entry of second line as one character and etc.
how do I separate it to rows (multidimensional array) or can I go through in while loop like with mysql_fetch_array?

Comment: I solved it
    `$lines = explode("\n", $attach);
    foreach($lines as $row) {
        $data = str_getcsv($row);
        ...
    }`
I know it's not clear and maybe like double `explode` but seems it work for me